# Broadcast Receiver doesn't work on Android Gingerbread

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I'm developing an Android application which uses a BroadcastReceiver to do some work while the phone is charging. On my Nexus 5 running Android 4.4.4 KitKat it works as expected, but a friend of mine tested this app on a Samsung Galaxy S running Android 2.3.6 Gingerbread and the app worked fine, but the BroadcastReceiver didn't worked.

My code is as follows:

```
public class PowerConnectionReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        startWakefulService(context, serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

And then I declare my BroadcastReceiver on the AndroidManifest:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".activities.PowerConnectionReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think I remember reading a similar issue on Samsung phones, might be worth having a quick google and see if anything pops up

Comment: Have you considered using regular broadcast receiver as shown on android developers: http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried with regular broadcast receiver as demonstrated with the following link:
http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html

Comment: That would be my last option, because if I register my BroadcastReceiver that way, I'll be forced to keep a service running all the time, which, of course, is not what I want. But if you provide sample code on how to implement this approach, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!